# Images are not indexed in google search console

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, images, xml-sitemap

I have submitted my sitemap which contains web pages and images. 78 web pages and 59 images are submitted. The web pages are indexed (71 out of 78), but images are not indexed. Why does that happen. Should I do anything additional for the images to be indexed.

Screen shot of search console> sitemap attached :

[image]

Working on magento 2

sitemap url : https://www.whitesouq.com/sitemap.xml